# StageXL and Color values

Tags: colors, dart, stagexl

Im attempting to set up an arbitrary color picker to get values to be passed to Graphics.fillColor().
the signature for that method is "dynamic fillColor(int color)", and so the color seems not to be an RGB/RGBA but instead some integer. The Color class defines a bunch of constants for these values, but I would like to be able to use any color that a user picks in my color picker.

I tried converting from RGB to Hex using this procedure:

```dart
String r_hex_str   = p_rbg_color_lst[0].toRadixString(16); //to hexadecimal
String g_hex_str   = p_rbg_color_lst[1].toRadixString(16);
String b_hex_str   = p_rbg_color_lst[2].toRadixString(16);
String rgb_hex_str = '0x$r_hex_str$g_hex_str$b_hex_str';

int color_rgb_int = int.parse(rgb_hex_str);

return color_rgb_int;
```

but the fillColor() method is not reacting to the new color argument. 
for illustration the above procedure takes [100, 145, 185] as the color RGB triplet and outputs 6590905 as the integer output.

StageXL.Color.Red constant is 4294901760

6590905 and 4294901760 are not even of the same length which tells me that the algo Im using is wrong...

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be using an extra two bytes to store the alpha value. So you would need to modify your code to add that:

```dart
String a_hex_str   = 255.toRadixString(16); // 255 is ff, or fully opaque
String r_hex_str   = p_rbg_color_lst[0].toRadixString(16); 
String g_hex_str   = p_rbg_color_lst[1].toRadixString(16);
String b_hex_str   = p_rbg_color_lst[2].toRadixString(16);
String rgb_hex_str = '0x$a_hex_str$r_hex_str$g_hex_str$b_hex_str';

int color_rgb_int = int.parse(rgb_hex_str);

return color_rgb_int;
```

Which gives 4284780985 for the input [100, 145, 185]

Answer (score 1):

Colors in StageXL are stored as ARGB integers. It's easier if you look at the value in hexadecimal format like this: 0xFFAABBCC. This value mean alpha = 0xFF, red = 0xAA, green = oxBB, blue = 0xCC.